# Does adding noexcept break binary compatibility?

Tags: c++, noexcept, binary-compatibility

Simple question: If change this:

```
void someMethod();
```

to

```
void someMethod() noexcept;
```

will it break binary compatibility, or does the method signature remain the same?

Comment: [Since C++17, "The noexcept-specification is a part of the function type". Before C++17, "The noexcept-specification is not a part of the function type"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec)

Comment: @Justin Even though it's a part of a function type, it [don't seem to affect](https://godbolt.org/g/QosEfk) mangled names on GCC nor on Clang.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that would be unspecified, so relying on that is dangerous.

Comment: @Justin this is a perfect answer, why posting it as a comment?

Comment: The C++ standard does not define the Binary Interface. So this is not answerable in the general case. It may work for a particular compiler implementation but that does not provide any guarantee that it will work for future versions of the compiler or other compilers.

Comment: @Justin you left out this part: "*Functions differing only in their exception specification cannot be overloaded (just like the return type, **exception specification is part of function type, but not part of the function signature**) (since C++17).*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Does the method signature remain the same ?**

Yes. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec :

> Functions differing only in their exception specification cannot be
>   overloaded (just like the return type, exception specification is part
>   of function type, but not part of the function signature) (since
>   C++17).

**Will it break binary compability ?**

Probably not, but standard doesn't guarentee anything (AFAIK).

Comment: You've said "no", but then quoted part of the spec which implies the answer is "yes". :)  " _exception specification is .. not part of the function signature_" - therefore, adding `noexcept` shouldn't change the function signature, and it should remain the same.

Comment: @davmac Your right, it should have been yes, good catch. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Itanium ABI specification](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-structure) (which GCC and clang follow), adding/removing `noexcept` from a function does not affect its mangled name. This is because `<exception-spec>` is not part of `<bare-function-type>`.

However the mangled name of the type of a function **pointer** *is* affected by `noexcept` (since they use `<function-type>` instead of `<bare-function-type>`) and therefore functions which take function pointers as arguments will change their mangled names depending on whether those function pointers are `noexcept` or not. GCC has a warning option `-Wnpexcept-type` for things like that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46849869/14013278).